# Prooving that $sign(x)=1$(?)

Tags: absolute-value, fake-proofs

Okay so I was having some thoughts about the $sign$ of real numbers and here is what I have:

$$(1) \forall x \in \Bbb R$$
$$(2) sign(x)= \frac{x}{|x|}$$
$$(3) |x|= \sqrt{x^2}$$
$$(4) sign(x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$
$$(5) sign(x)*\sqrt{x^2}=x$$
$$(6) \sqrt{x^2*sign(x)^2}=x$$
$$(7) x^2*sign(x)^2=x^2$$
$$(8) sign(x)^2= \frac{x^2}{x^2}$$
$$(9) sign(x)^2 =1$$
$$(10) sign(x)=1$$

The entire thing can be summarized as:
$$sign(x)^2=1$$
$$sign(x)=1$$

Here are my thoughts: this is probably a classic case of square/square root information destruction. In an example where information is not destroyed in the transition from line 9 to 10 there would be a $\pm$ leading to $sign(x)=\pm 1$ which is true for all $x \not = 0$.

Another thing is that line 6 is problematic because it implies that $|x|=x$ for all nonzero $x$, further implying that $x>0$ which is not nessacrily true.

Comment: What is your question?  I see that you have a sequence of logically connected statements which contains errors which you already noticed and pointed out.  You are aware that the result is false and you seem to be aware of where it is false already.  What do you want from us and what do you hope to gain by posting this?

Comment: I'm trying to confirm that my thoughts are correct.

Comment: (6) and(10) are wrong. Also, (2), (4), (8) require the restriction $x \ne 0$. And of course, (1) is not a statement.

Comment: The things to remember are $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ is false when $a$ and $b$ are negative and that $a^2=b^2$ does not imply that $a=b$.  Also $a=\sqrt{a^2}$ is false when $a$ is negative.  Your errors are moving from (5) to (6) and from (9) to (10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error $1$ in step $(2)$ occur  if $x=0$ . In that case you have to define $sign(x)=\frac{x}{\mid x\mid}$ if $x\ne0$ and  $sign(0)=0$

Error $2$ is in step $(6)$ as if $x<0$ this doesn't happen.

Error $3$ is in step$10$ as  $(sign(x))^2=1\Rightarrow  sign(x)=1,-1$

Answer (score 0):

Error (5) to (6) :How can you be sure that $sign(x) >0  \to sign(x)=\sqrt{(sign(x))^2}$
for example try (6) for $x=-2 $ you will see (6) is not true.